# Type Conversion error in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert stored Proc to LINQ using only LinqPad. I have following code in Linq

```
var myVar = (from st in Student
             where st.name == "abcd"
             select st).Take(10);

if (myVar.Any())
{
 // some statements
}
else
{
  myVar = (from emp in Employee
           where emp.name == "abcd"
           select emp).Take(10);   
}
```

But it is giving following error at select line in else block

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'
```

Can anyone know what is happening? How to solve it? How can I explicitly convert type in Linq?

Columns in both table are different. And I am not using any framework like entity framework etc. I just have the db of application and I am trying to convert all Stored Proc's into LINQ. And in the Stored Proc both values are caught in same variable and that's why I need them in same variable. So can it is possible in this scenario?

Comment: Looks pretty obvious, you're using the same variable to refer to two incompatible types. `var` is not dynamic. Fixing *that* is easy, declare a different variable for the second query. But solving your problem completely requires understanding of what you are intending to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am trying to convert Stored Proc into Linq in that both values are taken in same variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You queries returns different object, so you can't assign them to the same variable.

You could specify which properties you'd like to take from both queries and if they are the same it could work:

```
var myVar = (from st in Student
             where st.name == "abcd"
             select new
             {
                 st.name,
                 st.age
             }).Take(10);

if (myVar.Any())
{
 // some statements
}
else
{
  myVar = (from emp in Employee
           where emp.name == "abcd"
             select new
             {
                 emp.name,
                 emp.age
             }).Take(10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, But can I convert them both in one generic type? or is there any workaround for it? Because I need them in same variable.

Comment: You could try to find common base class for both and use that, but you'll have to declare your variable type explicitly (without `var`) then.

Comment: @user2262332, if both your Employee and Student inherit from a base class (Person, for example), then you could declare myVar as `IEnumerable<Person> myVar` instead of `var myVar`

Comment: Columns in both table are different. I am not using any framework like entity framework etc. I just have the db of application and I am trying to convert all SP's into LINQ. So can it is possible in this scenario?